# How to set a non-linear Y axis on a graph in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, charts

I need draw the chart similar type with the chart below but I don't know how to set up the Y axis value and resize to view as this.

[image: The chart]

Comment: you migh want to try this http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/charts.html

Comment: I use charts in Word all the time.  I've found its easiest to create the chart in Excel then `paste special` it into Word as an .EMF.  If you'll change it frequently (which I also do), you may try and do a linked chart, but I've found they are more trouble than a copy/paste.